# How to improve the speed of a for loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I'm using Datatables and Highcharts for a reporting screen but it is quite slow to load the chart (approx 10 Seconds), using `performance.now()` I can see the segment below is causing the delay:

Please note, the 'indexes' array contains 6500+ records.

```
var monthTO = {};
var indexes = TurnoverRepoTable.rows({ search: 'applied' }).indexes().toArray();
for (var i = 0; i < indexes.length; i++) {
    var cMonth = TurnoverRepoTable.cell(indexes[i], 2).data();
    var value = TurnoverRepoTable.cell(indexes[i], 6).data();
    if (monthTO[cMonth] === undefined) {
        monthTO[cMonth] = Number(value);
    } else {
        monthTO[cMonth] = monthTO[cMonth] + Number(value);
    }
}
```

So, I'd like to know if there a more efficient way of achieving this?

Cheers, Chris

Comment: This probably needs to move to the server as a separate request. Your loop relies on an API you don't have control over. It is unlikely you can affect the outcome without hacking data tables or jQuery. Make this a separate request to the server to get this transformation from there.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion Randy, unfortunately, that is not possible, as datatables has a lot of built-in functionality that adjusts the chart on the fly. The function above is not part of datatables or highcharts it is my own function that calculates the data for highcharts using the datatable data, I just wanted to ask if there are any improvements I could make to try and speed up the processing.

Answer (score 0):

Hi,
I have solved this issue by referencing the data directly (not by using the indexes), code below:

```
var dataset = TurnoverRepoTable.rows({ search: 'applied' }).data().toArray();

// For each row, extract the office and add the salary to the array
for (var i = 0; i < dataset.length; i++) {
    var cMonth = dataset[i].job.cMonth
    var value = dataset[i].job.estout
    if (monthTO[cMonth] === undefined) {
        monthTO[cMonth] = Number(value);
    } else {
        monthTO[cMonth] = monthTO[cMonth] + Number(value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect. Didn't know you had direct access to the data without calling the methods.